# Spring boot not able to connect to AmazonMq(rabbitmq)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

Hi I have a AmazonMq instance running rabbitmq and I am not able to connect to the broker using spring boot.

I am able to connect rabbitmq locally but not amazonmq(rabbitmq). My spring boot configuration is:

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.host=<host>
spring.rabbitmq.port=<port>
spring.rabbitmq.username=<username>
spring.rabbitmq.password=<password>
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=vhost
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/exly/emailqueue/config/RabbitMqChildConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: Factory method 'rabbitTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: Factory method 'rabbitTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:725) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2173) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2146) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2126) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.exly.core.config.RabbitMQConfig.rabbitTemplate(RabbitMQConfig.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.exly.emailqueue.config.RabbitMqChildConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63e2373.CGLIB$rabbitTemplate$11(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.exly.emailqueue.config.RabbitMqChildConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63e2373$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bac46a78.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.exly.emailqueue.config.RabbitMqChildConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63e2373.rabbitTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:396) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1225) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1342) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectHostPort(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:653) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:618) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:326) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:113) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:184) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:665) ~[amqp-client-5.14.2.jar:5.14.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
```

Please suggest how can to make connection successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue fix it was ssl issue which can be overcome by using

`CachingConnectio nFactory connectionFactory = newCachingConnectionFactory();`
`connectionFactory.setUri(env.getProperty("rabbitmq.address"))`

Answer (score 0):

I was recently facing this very same issue. The stacktrace I got looked a little bit different from the OP's one:

```
2024-02-29 14:35:08,011 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] INFO  o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Attempting to connect to: [<broker-host>:5671] [] []
2024-02-29 14:35:08,019 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] ERROR o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s). [] []
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:594) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:711) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:257) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2225) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2198) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2178) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:465) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1937) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1905) [spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1381) [spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223) [spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:132) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:128) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:399) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1236) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1184) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:632) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:607) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:557) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:505) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:329) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1236) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1184) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:632) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:607) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:557) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:203) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:121) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:188) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:672) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
    ... 1 more
```

Initially I used to specify the connection information as

```
spring.rabbitmq.host = <broker-host>
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5671
```

as I was under the impression that, if 5671 is specified as port, spring would automatically use SSL. Actually it seems to be the other way around as there is yet another spring rabbitmq property [`spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled):

> Whether to enable SSL support. Determined automatically if an address is provided with the protocol (amqp:// vs. amqps://).

That is, if you want to use SSL either set `spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled` to `true` or specify a broker address in [`spring.rabbitmq.addresses`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.rabbitmq.addresses) with the `amqps://` scheme.

Answer (score -1):

I guess here runtime `IOException` is not handle due to which it is failing.

Comment: But the jar is able to connect to rabbitmq in local system